# Read columns with readr using regular expressions

Tags: r, readr

I need to import data files with various column numbers. Finally, the code should be used by other co-workers being not very familiar with R. So it should be robust and without warning messages preferably. The main problem is that the headder is always ending with an additional "," which does not appear in the data below. Beside a whole bunch of unused columns the required columns are always labeled in the same way. I.e. there is always a certain string within the column name, but not necessarily the whole column name is identical.

The example code is a very simple approximation to my files. First, I would like to get rid of the error message due to the errornous comma at the end of the headder. Something like `skip_col = ncol(headder)`. And second, I would like to read only columns with `"*des*"` within the column name.

My approach to deal with it looks simple in this simplified example but is not very satisfying in my more complex code.

```
library(tidyverse)

read_csv("date,col1des,col1foo,col2des,col3des,col2foo,col3foo, 
          2015-10-23T22:00:00Z,0.6,-1.5,-1.3,-0.5,1.8,0 
          2015-10-23T22:10:00Z,-0.5,-0.6,1.5,0.1,-0.3,0.3
          2015-10-23T22:20:00Z,0.1,0.2,-1.6,-0.1,-1.4,-0.4
          2015-10-23T22:30:00Z,1.7,-1.2,-0.2,-0.4,0.3,0.3")

if (length(grep("des", names(data))) > 0) {
  des <- data[grep("des", names(data))]
  des <- bind_cols(date = data$date, des)
}
```

So in my full code, I get the following warning messages:

```
1. Missing column names filled in: 'X184' [184] 
2. Duplicated column names deduplicated: [long list of unrequired columns with dublicated names]
```

I would appreciate a solution within the tidyverse. As far as I found it is not possible to use regular expressions directly within the `read_csv` call to specify column names, right? So perhaps the only way is to read the headder first and build the `cols()` call out of that. But this exceeds my R knowledge.

**Edit:**

I wonder if something like this is possible:

```
headline <- "date,col1des,col1foo,col2des,col3des,col2foo,col3foo,"
head     <- headline %>% strsplit(",") %>% unlist(use.names = FALSE)
head_des <- head[grep("des", head)]
data     <- read_csv("mydata.csv", col_types = cols_only(head_des[1] = "d", head_des[2] = "d"))
```

I would like to `grep()` the column names befor reading the whole data.

Comment: `d <- suppressWarnings(readr::read_csv("text...")); d[, grep("des", names(d))]`?

Comment: Thanks, suppressing all warnings is pretty useful in my case. But I thought I could somehow avoid reading all the other columns within the `read_csv ()` call directly. The `grep ()` thing is what I'm doing right now. Unfortunately, it's not that elegant because I have to search multiple strings and up to 200 unused columns with lots of data.

Comment: In `grep` you may use `|`, e.g. `grep("str1|str2", names)`. This might accidentally match unwanted columns which you could solve with [regular expressions](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html), though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit no. 2

In reaction to your comment;
This works with your data-string:

```r
library(tidyverse)
yourData <- "date,col1des,col1foo,col2des,col3des,col2foo,col3foo, 
          2015-10-23T22:00:00Z,0.6,-1.5,-1.3,-0.5,1.8,0 
          2015-10-23T22:10:00Z,-0.5,-0.6,1.5,0.1,-0.3,0.3
          2015-10-23T22:20:00Z,0.1,0.2,-1.6,-0.1,-1.4,-0.4
          2015-10-23T22:30:00Z,1.7,-1.2,-0.2,-0.4,0.3,0.3"

data <- suppressWarnings(read_csv(yourData))

header <- names(data)
colList <- ifelse(str_detect(header,'des'),'c','_') %>% as.list
suppressWarnings(read_csv(yourData,col_types = do.call(cols_only, colList)))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   col1des col2des col3des
#>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1 0.6     -1.3    -0.5   
#> 2 -0.5    1.5     0.1    
#> 3 0.1     -1.6    -0.1   
#> 4 1.7     -0.2    -0.4
```

---

### EDIT

Trying to accomodate your edited wishes and with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318432/passing-named-list-to-cols-only) Post:

```r
library(tidyverse)


header <- suppressWarnings(readLines('file.csv')[1]) %>% 
  str_split(',',simplify = T)
colList <- ifelse(str_detect(header,'des'),'c','_') %>% as.list
suppressWarnings(read_csv(file = 'file.csv',col_types = do.call(cols_only, colList)))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   col1des col2des col3des
#>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1 0.6     -1.3    -0.5   
#> 2 -0.5    1.5     0.1    
#> 3 0.1     -1.6    -0.1   
#> 4 1.7     -0.2    -0.4
```

---

This is the most robust, most `tidyverse` way, I could come up with:

```r
library(tidyverse)

file <- suppressWarnings(readLines('file.csv')) %>% 
  str_split(',') 
dims <- file %>% map_int(~length(.))
if(any(dims != median(dims))){
  file[[which(dims != median(dims))]] <- file[[which(dims != median(dims))]][1:median(dims)]
}
data <- file %>% map_chr(~paste(.,collapse = ',')) %>% 
  paste(., sep = '\n') %>% read_csv
(data <- data %>% select(which(str_detect(names(data), pattern = 'des'))))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   col1des col2des col3des
#>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     0.6    -1.3    -0.5
#> 2    -0.5     1.5     0.1
#> 3     0.1    -1.6    -0.1
#> 4     1.7    -0.2    -0.4
```

Where `file.csv` contains your data.

Comment: If I just run your code which I have to admit I do not fully understand, it comes to the error message: `Error: 'date,col1des,col1foo,col2des,col3des,col2foo,col3foo2015-10-23T22:00:00Z,0.6,-1.5,-1.3,-0.5,1.8,02015-10-23T22:10:00Z,-0.5,-0.6,1.5,0.1,-0.3,0.32015-10-23T22:20:00Z,0.1,0.2,-1.6,-0.1,-1.4,-0.42015-10-23T22:30:00Z,1.7,-1.2,-0.2,-0.4,0.3,0.3' does not exist in current working directory`

Comment: You have to save your data in a text-file in your current working directory and name it 'file.csv' for it to work.
`readLines` opens a file and splits it into a `character`-vector with one entry per line of input.

Comment: `read_csv(yourData,col_types = do.call(cols_only, colList))` that is what I needed! Thanks!